# Nginx learning resources

Tags: nginx

I would like to learn Nginx (I'm trying to setup a nginx+thin(s) rails solution on linux). I know russian but the original nginx documentation is a bit hard to understand for me. Please advice on good resources available on Internet (blogs, community wikis, etc)

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SliceHost have some fantastic tutorials.

[Nginx Web Server](http://articles.slicehost.com/nginx)

[Ubuntu Intrepid - Nginx, rails and thin](http://articles.slicehost.com/2009/3/13/ubuntu-intrepid-nginx-rails-and-thin)

Make sure you check out the Nginx Wiki too.

[Nginx Wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main)

Also, join the mailing list. It's an excellent resource and the heart of the NGinx community.

[Nginx Mailing List](http://wiki.nginx.org/MailinglistSubscribe)